# Vue js cookies is undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cookies, web-deployment, vuejs3

I have installed the vue-cookies in my project.

I have included the following in the *main.js* file:

```js
createApp(App)
    .use(store)
    .use(router, axios, VueCookies)
```

Then the script part in the *App.vue* file contains the following:

```js
<script>
import Navbar from '@/components/layout/Navbar'
import axios from 'axios'


export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    Navbar
  },
  beforeCreate() {


    console.log(this.$cookies)
```

This says cookies is undefined, so I can't set or get any cookies.

If I add a `import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies'` the result is the same.

Before, I used *localStorage*, and I used this beforeCreate to read the login information from it. I want to start using cookies to store the token between sessions, as I have read it's more secure.

I have searched arout a little bit I have not read anything regarding cookie initialization or anything else I have to do so that `this.$cookies` is not undefined.

Comment: It seems vue-cookies is not officially supported on Vue 3 yet https://github.com/cmp-cc/vue-cookies/issues/59

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this library. But looking at npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-cookies

You have to import the library and use the plugin.

```
import VueCookies from 'vue-cookies';

Vue.use(VueCookies)
```

***I assume that you have installed the library previously.